# Isotope: jQuery not a function error using either jQuery or $ in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-isotope

Having a weird problem trying to call Isotope on this page (https://starmountaincapital.com/media-center-test/) where no matter whether I use '$' (which of course, I shouldn't, but tried anyway) or 'jQuery', I get the same Not a Function error in Console. The code is coming straight from Isotope with some additions to work with filtering:

```
var $grid = jQuery('.grid').isotope({
    // options
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        layoutMode: 'fitRows'
    });

// filter items on button click
    jQuery('.filter-button-group').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
        var filterValue = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');
        $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
    });
```

So is this written correctly?

Comment: Try to wrap the code inside jQuery(document).ready().

Answer (score 1):

The error message is not complaining about jQuery not being a function, but that the `.isotope property` of the jQuery object returned is not a function.

Looking at the network tab during page load shows a 404 error returned for the GET request to retrieve `isotope.js` from https://starmountaincapital.com/wp-content/themes/starmountain/js/isotope.js?ver=1

The server actually returns an HTML "NOT FOUND" error page. Check that `isotope.js` is correctly installed and, if so, in which folder it resides.

Answer (score 1):

What I found by visiting your site url is the **isotop.js** file is missing, can you please put the specific file in **js** folder of your theme and also write the handle for **isotop** in **dependency** of the javascript file where you have written the above code. 
E.G :

```
  wp_enqueue_script( 'isotop-js', 'path of isotop.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );

  wp_enqueue_script( 'your-js', 'path of your js', array( 'isotop-js' ), '1.0', true );
```

hope this wil work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Even after adding the isotope.js file correctly, the issue still pertained.

The problem was actually in the JS itself. After some more tweaking, I moved the code out of the footer and into isotope.js as follows:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
 var container = $('#post-grid'); //The ID for the list with all the blog posts
 container.isotope({ //Isotope options, 'item' matches the class in the PHP
 percentPosition: true,
 itemSelector : '.grid-item', 
   layoutMode : 'masonry',
   masonry: {
   columnWidth: '.grid-item'
  }
 });
```